# npm search doesn't search @types/

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using the latest version of NPM and I get no results when I search for known packages under @types/. For example this:

```
npm search @types/lodash
```

Returns:

> No matches found for "@types/lodash"

Is something screwed up with my npm? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPM search does not query scoped packages; see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8244

You can use http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/ instead

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.